# Getting Tor Control data through Stem and presenting on the web with web.py

Tags: python, web.py, tor

I have set up a Tor relay and would like it to display some statistics about itself on a webpage. Therefore I have installed lighttpd and web.py on the same box and it runs fine.

I have also installed Stem and I can get the data from the Tor control port succesfully using the Python example found here: https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html

Now I would like to combine the two and have web.py run the script and output the data to the website. I have fiddled with it for hours and I am out of clues. How do I need to write the python web.py app? Here is an example of an attemp that does not work:

```
import web
from stem.control import Controller

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
            controller.authenticate("mypassword")  # provide the password here if you set one

            bytes_read = controller.get_info("traffic/read")
            bytes_written = controller.get_info("traffic/written")

            return "My Tor relay has read %s bytes and written %s." % (bytes_read, bytes_written)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of stem looks right though you might want to look into [BW events](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/tortoise_and_the_hare.html) if you expand this to do multiple datapoints. As for web.py, the [examples on their site](http://webpy.org/skeleton/0.3) return a view.render.base instance, maybe that's the missing bit?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apparently I just forgot the quotes around the password... :) I am definitely going to expand it, and look in to the more advanced features of Stem. You're the author, right? Thank you for making it!

Comment: Yup. My pleasure and glad you like it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working now. Embarrasing, but it seems like all I did wrong was forgetting quotation marks around the password. I also moved the
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
up before the class. Don't now if it makes a difference. Now, on to bandwidth events to make a live updating web page with stats.